# Phrase matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nlp, matching, phrase

I would like to match phrases written by two people.

For example I may have one person saying "I am so happy" and the other "I am elated" and I need to match this two phrases as having the same meaning.

Is there such an algorithm at the moment? Where should I start trying to solve this problem or does the technology not exist at all?

P.S. I have done some programming but am not a programmer in the strict sense of the word.

Comment: can you assume that the words are written correctly?

Comment: can you link/post part of the data? the algorithm strongly depends on it. I doubt that the example you have given is representative.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is [sentiment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis), which is a reasonably difficult topic. Your question is probably too broad to fit well here.